# Immediate e-mail alerting for error 229 (permission denied)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

For a few reasons, I'd like to have all permission denied errors (number 229) emailed to me. Checking master.sys.messages shows that is_event_logged for this error is 0. Thus that rules out using SQL Server Agent error alerts, which rely on the SQL Server error log (I've tested this - I get no alert).

I figured I'd peek in mssqlsystemresource and look at the view definition for sys.messages, thinking maybe I could update is_event_logged for the message in question. But this view gets the system error message from `OpenRowset(TABLE SYSERRORS)`, so that's a no-go.

Is there a reasonably simple way I can get all 229 errors emailed to me immediately (or within maybe 30 seconds) without harming server performance? A 60-second cool-down between emails would probably be a good idea too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, damn it, not 30 seconds after I post this, I stumble across sp_altermessage (naturally, after spending a significant amount of time trying to figure out if I could do this with extended events). So if anybody else is wondering how to do this:

```
EXEC sp_altermessage 229, 'WITH_LOG', 'true'
```

Comment: I used to do this back in SQL Server 2000 when I was full on DBA. Interesting what you catch folk trying...

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure I'll find a snoop here or there using Access or Management Studio or something. Mostly I want to make sure accounts have *enough* permission. A number of users/roles have way too many privileges, and I'm trying to dial it back without breaking our ERP/sales software. Combined with the user errors trace I have running on the server, this should give me enough forensic detail (though I'd love to figure out how to get the user name to appear in the alert email).